# How does the scoring system work?

Tags: dmc-devil-may-cry

I've seen lots of theories thrown around about what sorts of things can affect your score and style meter, but lots of those theories seem to be based on anecdotal evidence or knowledge of previous DMC games (which may or may not have any relevance here). I'm looking for verified, concrete information about all of the things that affect it, if possible.

For example:

- Does it differ between difficulty levels?
- Does "combo variety" matter, and if so, what are the rules?
- Is it affected by the hits you inflict or receive (either damage amount, or number of hits)?
- Based on the above, are there any reliable rules of thumb to follow for people who want to chase high scores?

Comment: For the combo variety, the in-game tutorial mentions that you get a point value for a given move and is reduced each time you use it again in the same combo. What's not clear is whether this resets after a certain number of moves. As for general rules of thumb, the system seems to love it when you switch up weapons. Obviously you should also avoid getting. Parries/dodges also count but probably more risky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combo variety is really all that matters. From personal experience, its real easy to rank up to a triple S by switching between the weapons constantly. Do 2 different combos with one weapon, switch, do 2 combos, switch, 2 combos, etc. in that pattern. You can go back to the first weapon in the combo string after switching through 2 other weapons if you want to guarantee that the rank continues to grow. When fighting red or blue colored demons, do thee combos before switching between the weapons, throw in aerial combos to make things even easier.